# Not sure how to construct a URL to call a web service method

Tags: c#, web-services, powershell, soap

I have just written my first SOAP web service.  It's fairly simple.  It just runs Powershell scripts or functions in a couple different manners.  My problem is that I'm not sure how to construct a URL to call my methods.  I'm sure it's just due to my inexperience with web services.

The method definition is RunPowershellScriptWithArgsExportJson(string scriptPath, string[] scriptArgs).  The scriptPath is a local path like C:\Scripts\Testing.ps1.  scriptArgs could potentially be anything.

I've verified that I can see the xml response in a browser by entering the path to the asmx. It was similar to http://PCName.com/PsWebService/ServiceName.asmx. (We're only using this service on our internal network so I'm using the computer name instead of a domain name in the URL)

I can also invoke the methods from remote computers with Powershell and its New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet, but that doesn't require a URL that includes method calls. So the web service appears to work.  I'm just not sure how to call it in a URL which is ultimately what I need.

Could someone provide me with an example of a URL that would work to call my RunPowershellScriptWithArgsExportJson method correctly? I've tried several things and also read a few blogs and tech articles, but so far I'm just getting random URL exceptions on everything I try.

Comment: It's a SOAP service, right? The URL does not include the method name or parameters. Also, you should not have used ASMX to construct the service. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Ok that's good to know.  It's a really simple web service, so I'll create a new project in VS and see what I can do with that.  After reading your comments, I looked at the tech net article I followed to create the service, and sure enough it was from 2008.  That'll teach me not to pay closer attention.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: The easiest way is to just use fiddler or wireshark to trace the traffic when you invoke the method you're after.